# Reason for に particle in sentence instead of の

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-の

I have come across sentence and I understand what its trying to say, but I don't understand why に is used with 特別. I was really expecting a の particle instead to modify related noun phrase 旅のサポート

Why wouldn't it be の? Why is it に?

> 今回は特別**に**旅のサポートをしてくれる方も来てるんです
>
> My translation: This time, there are even people coming who will provide special trip support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「今回{こんかい}は特別{とくべつ}（　）旅{たび}のサポートをしてくれる方{かた}も来{き}てるんです。」

What particles can we correctly use in the blank in the sentence above?

The answer is 「な」 and 「に」.  I am afraid that 「の」 is not a natural-sounding choice here.

「特別**な**」 functions **adjectivally** to modify nouns only.  In this sentence, it can modify either 「旅」 or 「サポート」.

「特別**に**」 functions **adverbially** to modify verbs and adjectives.  In this particular sentence, it can modify either 「してくれる」 or 「来てる」.

The author/speaker's choice is 「に」, which means that s/he wanted to use  「特別に」 adverbially.  S/he wanted to say 「特別にサポートしてくれる」 or 「特別に来てる（んです）」.  Which one it is, it is difficult to tell without further context, but I will add that either interpretation would be natural here.

Comment: So does this mean that all な-adjectives can use に as a substitute to modify the verb? I have come across another similar example, where its 安全に:

運転の方はプロですから、**安全に**釣り場で連れて行ってくれますよ！
My Translation: Because they're a professional driver, he will safely take us to a fishing spot.

I see in Jisho that 安全 is classified as a な-adjective, but not a "normal" adjective. So I'm not sure if I can use the same grammar construction as the one you described in your answer